# Create package for CV with options given separately

Tags: package-writing

I wrote my CV in latex and I want to share it with the world but now it's a mess of a code. I want to write a package so that the user could just do

```
\addjob{1}{Job title 1}
\addshortdesc{1}{short description}
\addstartdate{1}{start date}
\addenddate{1}{end date}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplisment one}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplisment two}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplisment three}

\addjob{2}{Job title 2}
\addshortdesc{2}{short description}
\addstartdate{2}{start date}
\addenddate{2}{end date}
\addaccomplishment{2}{accomplisment one}
\addaccomplishment{2}{accomplisment two}
```

I tried googling but I couldn't find a way to create something like I want. Just the usual new command definition that needs everything as an input right away.

Can this be done? I've never done anything like this. Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to make a document class. There are several resources online, e.g., [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class) and [this](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide-historic.pdf). You might find my simple CV class project [here](https://github.com/jessexknight/nacv) helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line is, everything reduces to saving stuff in macros and using them later. This basic idea could be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\job@list}{}
\newcommand*{\addjob}[5]{% \addjob{label}{title}{start date}{end date}{description}
   \@namedef{job@#1}{#2}%
   \@namedef{job@#1@accomplishment}{}%
   \g@addto@macro\job@list{{#1}}%
   \@namedef{job@#1@startdate}{#3}%
   \@namedef{job@#1@enddate}{#4}%
   \@namedef{job@#1@desc}{#5}%
}
\newcommand*{\addaccomplishment}[2]{%
   \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname job@#1@accomplishment\endcsname{{#2}}%
}
\newcommand*{\printjobs}{%
   \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@tfor\noexpand\x:=\job@list}\@tempa
   \do{%
   \par\noindent
   \textbf{\@nameuse{job@\x}}
   (\@nameuse{job@\x @startdate}--\@nameuse{job@\x @enddate}):
   \@nameuse{job@\x @desc}
   \begin{itemize}
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\print@accomplishments\csname job@\x @accomplishment\endcsname\relax
   \end{itemize}
   }%
}
\newcommand*{\print@accomplishments}[1]{%
   \ifx#1\relax\else\item#1\expandafter\print@accomplishments\fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}% for the example

\addjob{1}{Job title 1}{1.1.1900}{2.2.1900}{short description}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplishment one}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplishment two}
\addaccomplishment{1}{accomplishment \href{tex.stackexchange.com}{three}}

\addjob{2}{Job title 2}{3.3.1900}{4.4.1901}{short description}
\addaccomplishment{2}{accomplishment \textbf{one}}
\addaccomplishment{2}{accomplishment two}

\begin{document}

\printjobs

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, in order to make a sensible package out of this you must introduce a lot of improvements, e.g. checking that you don't use the same job "label" twice, that the date or the accomplishments exist before you try to print them, guarding against non expandable stuff in the arguments, and so on... that's left to the reader as exercise `:-)`

Comment: Thanks! This is a great starting point for me to start figuring out the rest.

Comment: Any reason why I can't add what you wrote in another .tex file and call it in the main one with input?

Comment: @M.O. That would in fact be the reasonable thing to do. I put everything in one file just for convenience here.

Comment: Yeah it was just an error of mine. I was able to make it work and I've advanced a lot. Any reason why it returns an error if I put an \href link as an accomplishment?

Comment: @M.O. That's one of the improvements `:-P` I was assuming that only pure text came in the accomplishments. Fixed that, but something similar might happen again. As I said, this is a basic idea of how such a package would work, not a usable draft.